# Powershell output and "Run and Debug" terminal output corruption using "ConvertFrom-Json"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

till yesterday I thought that I become an idiot, but this morning I was able to reproduce a problem that is affecting the "Run and Debug" terminal output in Vscode and Powershell
The output of the commands is displayed in the proper way as you can see here : [image: here]

If I try to add the option "ConvertFrom-Json", the font color is changing to black as you can see here: [image: here].
The situation is even worst in Powershell (5.1.19041 and 7.0.3): the ouput become a huge black block.

I already tried to use another user and another computer with a different user profile, same issue (with different Windows 10 builds).

Comment: What if you enclose the whole az command in brackets ? Something like `(az reservations ... --output json) | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: same corrupted output